# Android tablet does not receive notifications when screen is off

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, notifications

I have a Ainol Novo 7 Aurora v3 tablet using unofficial ROM, rooted, CM10.

Android OS version is 4.1.2, and I found that it cannot receive notifications such as WhatsApp.

After the screen is turned on, notifications are received.

- Wi-Fi Settings > Advanced > Always ON
- valid Wi-Fi Internet connection is connected

How can I resolve the issue ?

---

**Update** I found a [thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42272) about this issue, and I verified the issue is happening on my device with ping tool. When the screen is off, ping is immediately timed out.

However, Android 4.1.2 does not have the `/system/etc/wifi/WCNSS_qcom_cfg.ini` file. I'm stuck.

Comment: Possibly a silly question: are you SURE the cfg file isn't there? Have you enabled "Show Hidden Files" in your file explorer. ES File explorer has this option for sure, so maybe try that first.

Comment: I use Root Explorer, double checked with other 4.1.2 devices. No such config file

Comment: Do you have a battery saver app like Juice Defender [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.latedroid.juicedefender&hl=es)?